# Strange issue with select options in IE9

Tags: html, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-9

I am working on a multiselect option with jQuery UI Multiselect. The items are all inside a jQuery UI accordion. On selecting items the UI is getting updated, and code is written for persisting the selection even if we switch to another panel in Accordion. Everything works fine in FF, Chrome, IE8, IE10 but not in IE9.

After debugging and comparing in IE Dev tools I found the following -[image]

When I log inner html of select element in Dev Tools with

```
console.log(selectElement.html())
```

I am getting the "selected" attribute in IE9. And, when I want to remove "selected" attribute for each item manually like -

```
item.removeAttr("selected")
```

it shows error as undefined.

So, is there any issue with selected attribute in IE9?

Answer (score 1):

Still couldn't figure out the exact reason and fix. But, resolved it through adding another attribute to  tags.

If any one has any idea about this please post your thoughts.